# C++ Counting inversions in array, Fatal Signal 11 (BIT)

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-indexed-tree

I was given [this](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/inversion-of-array/0) challenge in a programming "class". Eventually I decided to go for the "Binary Indexed Trees" solution, as data structures are a thing I'd like to know more about. Implementing BIT was somewhat straight forward, things after that - not so much. I ran into "Fatal Signal 11" when uploading the solution to the server, which, from what I've read, is somewhat similar to a Null pointer exception. Couldn't figure out the problem, decided to check out [other](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-inversions-array-set-3-using-bit/) solutions with BIT but stumbled upon the same problem.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



/*    <BLACK MAGIC COPIED FROM geeksforgeeks.org>     */
int getSum(int BITree[], int index){
    int sum = 0;
    while (index > 0){
        sum += BITree[index];
        index -= index & (-index);
    }
    return sum;
}
void updateBIT(int BITree[], int n, int index, int val){
    while (index <= n){
       BITree[index] += val;
       index += index & (-index);
    }
}
/*    <BLACK MAGIC COPIED FROM geeksforgeeks.org>     */




int Count(int arr[], int x){
    int sum = 0;
    int biggest = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        if (biggest < arr[i]) biggest = arr[i];
    }

    int bit[biggest+1];

    for (int i=1; i<=biggest; i++) bit[i] = 0;

    for (int i=x-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        sum += getSum(bit, arr[i]-1);
        updateBIT(bit, biggest, arr[i], 1);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;


    int *arr = new int[x];
    for (int temp = 0; temp < x; temp++) cin >> arr[temp];

        /*sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); <-- someone suggested this, 
        but it doesn't change anything from what I can tell*/

    cout << Count(arr,x);

    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

I am quite stumped on this. It could be just some simple thing I'm missing, but I really don't know. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` would be the size of the pointer. It won't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have condition that every number lies between 1 and 10<sup>18</sup>. So, your biggest number can be 10<sup>18</sup>. This is too much for the following line:

```
int bit[biggest+1];
```

Comment: Oh boy, I completely ignored the fact that (even though the condition they gave me was 10^9) arr[biggest+1] is too big... Oh that's a goof..